# How to hide the author box of a specific WordPress user?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a way to hide or remove the Author box for a specific user, but not for all users.

Currently, I have a website at the following:
https://afterthoughtsblog.net

And I am trying to hide or remove the Author Box for all of the posts from this specific user - her user ID is 1 and you can see a blog post from her here:
https://afterthoughtsblog.net/2019/08/the-evolution-of-a-charlotte-mason-homeschool-schedule.html

Is there any code or plugin that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the post template (`single.php` or `single-post.php`) if the `$post->post_author` does not equal `1` and only then display the author box.

```
<?php if ( $post->post_author !== '1' ): ?>
  ... author box
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried that code and it did not work. I placed it in the single.php file.